# Opposite of "qualifier"

Tags: terminology

What is the appropriate term for a modifying clause that generalizes, rather than limits, the preceding statement? For example: "It is crucial to bring a canteen on the trip, even if the sky is cloudy."

Comment: It's also a _"qualifier"_. Qualification is not implicitly related to limitation; it's just that's a more common kind of qualification than extension (the clause cited here is not really a generalization, just an emphatic extension of the boundary conditions).

Comment: What Prof. Lawler said. Even making something more general can be seen as limiting it in that direction. It is defining a thing by its *qualities* and thus narrowing its scope even as it may appear to be broadening it. More general means less specific. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Carla Lowe, in 'Daily Writing Tips', gives the most appropriate definition of **modifier** that I've come across:

> [W]hat’s a modifier? A modifier is a word, phrase, or clause that
>   “modifies” (says something about, describes, clarifies, qualifies,
>   limits – or adjusts or even alters) another word, phrase, or clause.

But she should probably add *extends the boundary conditions of, and/or emphasises* after 'limits', as John implies.

Here, 'even if the sky is cloudy' modifies the whole main clause.

It is important to bear in mind the linguistics usage of **modify** in such analyses; the main 'everyday' sense is 'to adjust in a relatively minor way' - although to the heroes at *Top Gear*, that might involve converting a saloon car to a boat.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a semantic definition, and modification is a syntactic phenomenon, and is not properly defined by its semantics. For instance, what is said above about _a modifier_ is also true of _a predicate_; however, we wouldn't want to say that the verb phrase _tires fast_ **modifies** the subject NP _Bill_ in the sentence _Bill tires fast_.

Comment: And that's a particular-grammar-dependent statement. According to a different take,  _Two of these relationships, argumenthood and modification, are at bottom semantic relationships (although the expression of argumenthood is more constrained in natural language than purely semantic considerations would dictate) ..._ ( http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch3.html )

Comment: That's syntactic **theory**. I.e, its goal is to unify all parts of syntax under abstract categories (like X-bar theory, etc); I'm concerned with syntactic **description**, which requires specification of exact tests for constituency and structural relations, rather than (quite possibly true, and certainly very interesting) generalizations about what they might be related to. While it's certainly true that there's no "interface" between semantics and syntax, it's equally true that semantic definitions of syntactic phenomena usually claim too much or account for too little.

Comment: Yes - I thought I'd got the parts-of-speech analysis sewn up. Now I'm finding I've just got different dustbin classes with fancier and slightly more logical names. The dustbins are lighter, but they're cluttering up the garden.

Comment: There are several kinds of categories that have to be distinguished, since different rules apply to them. Phrase Structures use categories like _Noun, Verb,_ and _Verb Phrase_; Grammatical Relations use categories like _Subject_ and _Object_; Anaphoric Relations use categories like _Antecedent_ and _Coreferent_; Dependency Relations use categories like _Modifier of_ and _Complement of_. For instance. BTW, this is all spelled out clearly in [McCawley 1998](http://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/S/bo3613599.html)

Answer (score 0):

This an adverbial prepositional phrase of *concession*. Adverbs tell time, place, degree, manner, cause, purpose, condition, or concession.